# Cloudfront seems to lose my JSON Web Token on refresh

Tags: express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, passport.js, amazon-cloudfront, express-jwt

I'm using Passport.js in an Express app, and using a JWT Strategy.

My Elastic Beanstalk/EC2 server is behind Cloudfront. I'm running a Vue SPA out of an S3 bucket. Cloudfront is configured to serve my index.html file in the case of a 403 or 404 (when someone refreshes the page).

ON my local, everything is great. I can visit my profile page, and all user data loads. When I refresh, I think all user data loads again without issue.

When I deploy to AWS, refreshing the profile loses all user data; it seems as though my JWT token is lost and I no longer have a user.

If I point my API directly to the ec2 instance (thus bypassing Cloudfront) everything runs perfectly.

I'm not quite sure where to start debugging this. The problem seems isolated to Cloudfront, but I'm not sure which configuration settings to adjust.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make sure my cloudfront distribution was forwarding the Authorization header to the origin. After I did that everything worked perfectly.